# How to pass params and headers to aiohttp ClientSession

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I wish to pass `params` and `headers` to `aiohttp.ClientSession` as shown [here](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyListingsLatest).

This is what I have tried:

```py
    async def make_request(self, url, headers, params):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers, params=params) as session:
            async with self.limit, session.get(url=url) as response:
                await asyncio.sleep(self.rate)
                resp = await response.read()
                return resp
```

```py
async def process(url, url_id, update_id, rate, limit):
    limit = asyncio.BoundedSemaphore(limit)

    f = Fetch(
        rate=rate,
        limit=limit,
    )

    if "coinmarketcap" in url:
        params = {
            'start': '1',
            'limit': '1',
            'convert': 'USD,BTC'
        }
        headers = {
            'Accepts': 'application/json',
            'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': API_KEY,
        }
    else:
        params = {}
        headers = {}

    result = await f.make_request(url, headers, params)
```

But I am getting the error:

```py
Unexpected Argument at:
async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers, params=params) as session
```

I wish to set headers if let's say the url was [coinmarketcap](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyListingsLatest) and `no params/headers` otherwise.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The params attribute can't be passed to the session. You'll need to send it in the get call, like so:

```
    async def make_request(self, url, headers, params):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=header) as session:
            async with self.limit, session.get(url=url, params=params) as response:
                await asyncio.sleep(self.rate)
                resp = await response.read()
                return resp
```

You can send the headers in the client session initialisation or in the get call. I think either will work.

Comment: oh my world! how did i miss that? thanks @PirateNinjas :)