# this cod is true but in this website('hepsiburada.com') returns 403.How can i fix this?

Tags: python, asynchronous, aiohttp

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('https://www.hepsiburada.com/') as response:
            print("Status:", response.status)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

this cod is true but in this website('hepsiburada.com') returns 403.How can i fix this ?

Comment: Welcome, [403 means forbidden](https://httpstatuses.com/403). Is there a login required for the page?

Comment: Thank you for answer.But there is no login required

Answer (score 1):

The server tries to prevent web scraping by default by denying requests without a user agent in the headers. Instead of returning a success status code of 206, it returns the forbidden status code of 403.

These are the headers I typically use for requests to mimic the browser:

```
WEB_HDRS = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,text/plain,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,application/_json;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Charset': 'Windows-1252,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8;q=0.5',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
}
```

Then add the `headers` keyword argument to the `aiohttp.ClientSession` call as [stated by the docs](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#client-session):

```
aiohttp.ClientSession('https://www.hepsiburada.com/', headers=WEB_HDRS)
```

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61615189/how-to-pass-params-and-headers-to-aiohttp-clientsession) for how other folks create sessions.